# $wpdb not working on custom (woocommerce) tables

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to retrieve some order details saved by woocommerce in custom tables this plugin has created and I am getting two issues.

With the following code the page just breaks with no errors visible, even if I enable error reporting on the page

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->woocommerce_order_items = $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_order_items';
$wpdb->woocommerce_order_itemmeta = $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_order_itemmeta';

$therapists = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT 
u.ID, 
m1.meta_value       as first_name,
m2.meta_value       as last_name,
m3.meta_value       as pma_skills,
m4.meta_value       as pma_photo,
m5.meta_value       as pma_job_titles,
m6.post_id          as order_id,
m7.order_item_id    as order_item_id,
m8.meta_value       as status,
m9.meta_value       as expiry_date,
m10.meta_value      as product_id

FROM $wpdb->users AS u

LEFT JOIN $wpdb->usermeta AS m1 
ON u.ID = m1.user_id  AND m1.meta_key = 'first_name'

LEFT JOIN $wpdb->usermeta AS m2 
ON u.ID = m2.user_id AND m2.meta_key = 'last_name'

LEFT JOIN $wpdb->usermeta AS m3
ON u.ID = m3.user_id AND m3.meta_key = 'pma_skills'

LEFT JOIN $wpdb->usermeta AS m4
ON u.ID = m4.user_id AND m4.meta_key = 'pma_photo'

LEFT JOIN $wpdb->usermeta AS m5
ON u.ID = m5.user_id AND m5.meta_key = 'pma_job_titles'

LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS m6
ON u.ID = m6.meta_value

LEFT JOIN $wpdb->woocommerce_order_items AS m7
ON order_id = m7.order_id AND m7.order_item_type = 'line_item'

LEFT JOIN $wpdb->woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS m8
ON m7.order_item_id = m8.order_item_id AND m8.meta_key = '_subscription_status'

LEFT JOIN $wpdb->woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS m9
ON m7.order_item_id = m9.order_item_id AND m9.meta_key = '_subscription_expiry_date'

LEFT JOIN $wpdb->woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS m10
ON m7.order_item_id = m10.order_item_id AND m10.meta_key = '_product_id'

WHERE m1.meta_value IS NOT NULL");
```

With the following code instead the custom tables get removed from the query like so

LEFT **JOIN  AS** m7 ON order_id = m7.order_id AND m7.order_item_type = 'line_item'

**instead of**

LEFT **JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items AS** m7 ON order_id = m7.order_id AND m7.order_item_type = 'line_item'

```
global $wpdb;

$therapists = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT 
u.ID, 
m1.meta_value       as first_name,
m2.meta_value       as last_name,
m3.meta_value       as pma_skills,
m4.meta_value       as pma_photo,
m5.meta_value       as pma_job_titles,
m6.post_id          as order_id,
m7.order_item_id    as order_item_id,
m8.meta_value       as status,
m9.meta_value       as expiry_date,
m10.meta_value      as product_id

FROM $wpdb->users AS u

LEFT JOIN $wpdb->usermeta AS m1 
ON u.ID = m1.user_id  AND m1.meta_key = 'first_name'

LEFT JOIN $wpdb->usermeta AS m2 
ON u.ID = m2.user_id AND m2.meta_key = 'last_name'

LEFT JOIN $wpdb->usermeta AS m3
ON u.ID = m3.user_id AND m3.meta_key = 'pma_skills'

LEFT JOIN $wpdb->usermeta AS m4
ON u.ID = m4.user_id AND m4.meta_key = 'pma_photo'

LEFT JOIN $wpdb->usermeta AS m5
ON u.ID = m5.user_id AND m5.meta_key = 'pma_job_titles'

LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS m6
ON u.ID = m6.meta_value

LEFT JOIN $wpdb->prefixwoocommerce_order_items AS m7
ON order_id = m7.order_id AND m7.order_item_type = 'line_item'

LEFT JOIN $wpdb->prefixwoocommerce_order_itemmeta AS m8
ON m7.order_item_id = m8.order_item_id AND m8.meta_key = '_subscription_status'

LEFT JOIN $wpdb->prefixwoocommerce_order_itemmeta AS m9
ON m7.order_item_id = m9.order_item_id AND m9.meta_key = '_subscription_expiry_date'

LEFT JOIN $wpdb->prefixwoocommerce_order_itemmeta AS m10
ON m7.order_item_id = m10.order_item_id AND m10.meta_key = '_product_id'

WHERE m1.meta_value IS NOT NULL");
```

I also get a broken page with no errors if I just use full table names rather than variables.

You can see the results on this page http://psicologialondra.com/testpage/

What am I doing wrong? I am trying to use the recommended code but it just does not seem to work :(

Answer (score 0):

The second code cannot work, you definitely need the first. Does the query print out if you use that one? I would also check if the get_results method returns any error using **var_dump**.

Comment: It returns an Array or NULL